# Do rapid serial edits get auto-reversed?

Tags: discussion, edits, serial-edits

I know rapidly casting votes can get picked up by one of the many nightly routines and subsequently get undone.

Is this also true of edits?

I ask because I was considering working through questions that all contain the same [certain phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22please%20suggest%20me%22) which is often an indicator of poorly-written titles/questions. By working through search results I imagine I'd be able to get through many edits in a relatively short amount of time (I have edit privileges).

Before I do so, I wanted to make sure it wouldn't get seen as vandalism and get reversed?

Comment: I don't _think_ so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No they do not, but one thing you have to keep in mind is that every edit bumps the post to the home page, so you should only make the edits in small groups (I usually do 30-40 at a time) to keep the lists from being flooded with old posts. It irritates some people. I'm not saying you have to wait an hour between each group, but complete a group of posts and then take a ten minute break or so, browse a few questions, and then get back to it. There's no hurry, the posts will be there tomorrow.

Since you have full edit rights, you shouldn't have a problem. These types of edits are frequently rejected in the suggested edits queue though, as they tend to only correct the phrase and not address any other issues in the post. I strongly suggest that while you're going through these posts that you at least attempt to fix other blatant issues with the posts, rather than just making the quit change and clicking finish. Not only will it slow you down slightly to put more room between the posts you're bumping, but it will help further improve the quality of the posts. I think this is kind of obviously with the specific phrase you've chosen (it's hard not to rephrase it).

Also, please do not bother editing closed questions which are unlikely to be reopened. No one enjoys seeing closed questions get bumped up when they can't answer or really do anything with them.

Comment: Thanks for the authoritative answer. I'm expecting there to be multiple issues with these, so it may not be as rapid as planned when I get round to it!

Comment: I suppose if we have enough high-rep users loitering on the home page, they can help us flag or get rid of the closed questions that get bumped back up. Particularly useful when it comes to mass retags.

Answer (score 6):

Edits are never automatically rolled back, ever. It is always a manual operation, performed by anybody who has full edit privileges.

If you edit too many of *your own* posts in rapid succession, though, you'll be blocked from editing for a while (I believe it's a day the last time that happened to me), and the next post you try to edit will be auto-flagged for possible vandalism for moderators to check for any anomalous behavior.

Most of these cases turn out not to be vandalism, as most users aren't editing their posts to vandalize them, but rather are a little too eager to improve them. However, some people are known to go... berserk, so we have these measures in place in case we have a user who does try to mess up all their posts, in which case us mods or devs can manually roll all their edits back.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question of editing other people's posts (animuson has covered that already), but I thought this would be useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, serial edits do not get reversed as long as the post was valid. On the English Language and Usage site, a few of us went on a "thank you" deletion spree (as well as a few sprees on commonly misspelled words) during the summer. Many, many posts ended up getting bumped to the front page, but none of us lost our edit rights or had those edits reversed. As long as you have sufficient reputation to edit without putting it in the edit queue, I think your account will be fine.